# Query two Cloud Firestore collections into 1 object

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flamelink-cms

I am using Flamelink as a headless CMS integrated with Firebase. All of my string fields are working just fine; I am just having a little trouble getting a URL of the media that was uploaded to Firebase Storage.

The collection that I'm getting my string fields from is `fl_content`
The fields are:

```
string1
string2
imageUpload
```

Within Firebase, I can see the data that gets saved from Flamelink:

```
string1: "Titanium Tee"
string2: "Lower your handicap by 50 with premium Titanium golf tees!"
```

imageUpload returns an array with a reference to `fl_files` (a different collection in Firebase)

```
imageUpload:
    0 fl_files/ZqVeXI3vX0rFDuJVDzuR
```

Under fl_files > ZqVeXI3vX0rFDuJVDzuR, I'm able to see the full filename of the image I upload; the documents in `fl_files` have a `file` field. **I need to get this filename sent to my object so that I'm able to use the images in my UI.**

Here's my progress:

Task:

```
struct Task{
    var string1:String
    var string2:String
    //var imageUpload:String
    var counter:Int
    var id: String

    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "string1": string1,
            "string2": string2,
            //"imageUpload": imageUpload,
            "counter": counter
        ]
    }
}

extension Task{
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any], id: String) {
        guard   let string1 = dictionary["string1"] as? String,
            let string2 = dictionary["string2"] as? String,
            //let imageUpload = dictionary["imageUpload"] as? String,
            let counter = dictionary["counter"] as? Int
            else { return nil }

        self.init(string1:string1, string2: string2, /*imageUpload: imageUpload,*/ counter: counter, id: id)
    }
}
```

VC:

```
private var documents: [DocumentSnapshot] = []
public var tasks: [Task] = []
private var listener : ListenerRegistration!

fileprivate func baseQuery() -> Query {
    return Firestore.firestore().collection("fl_content").limit(to: 50)
}

fileprivate var query: Query? {
    didSet {
        if let listener = listener {
            listener.remove()
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.query = baseQuery()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.listener.remove()
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    listenerStuff()
}

func listenerStuff(){
    self.listener =  query?.addSnapshotListener { (documents, error) in
        guard let snapshot = documents else {
            print("Error fetching documents results: \(error!)")
            return
        }

        let results = snapshot.documents.map { (document) -> Task in
            if let task = Task(dictionary: document.data(), id: document.documentID) {
                return task
            }
            else {
                fatalError("Unable to initialize type \(Task.self) with dictionary \(document.data())")
            }
        }

        self.tasks = results
        self.documents = snapshot.documents

        self.databaseTableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

**How do I query fl_files so that I can populate the imageUpload property of Task with the URL of the uploaded image? Do I do another separate query? Or can I access fl_files from baseQuery()?**

EDIT

Here's my attempt at getting to fl_files from fl_content. Trying to just simply populate 2 text fields an an image field (in a UITableViewCell) from Firebase. Is `property` what I need in getdocument?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "databaseCellID", for: indexPath) as! DatabaseTableViewCell
    let item = tasks[indexPath.row]

    cell.label1.text = item.string1
    cell.label2.text = item.string2
    let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("fl_content").document(item.id)
    print("PARENT \(docRef.parent)")
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let property = document.get("imageUpload")
            // TODO - use this property to get to fl_files?
            print("Document data: \(property!)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is probably to write a small [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) that will respond to the uploaded files and place the image URL automatically in your desired collection, allowing for easier querying.

We will attach an `onCreate` listener to the `fl_files` collection, then write the downloadURL to the corresponding `fl_content` document when we see that a new file was created. Note that your actual content fields may be different from the examples I have used here (I'm not personally familiar with Flamelink).

```js
/**
 * Firebase Cloud Function deployed to your same project.
 */

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';

exports.newFileUploaded = functions.firestore
  .document('fl_files/{newFileID}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => { 

    const fileID = context.params.newFileID;
    const fileData = snap.data();

    // get whatever data you want out of fileData..
    // (let's assume there is a downloadURL property with the URL of the image)
    const downloadURL = fileData.downloadURL;

    // write that download URL to the corresponding fl_content document
    // (assuming the file ID is the same as the content ID)
    const contentRef = firestore().collection('fl_content').doc(fileID);

    // update the imageURL property, returning the Promise, so the function
    // does not terminate too early
    const updateData = { imageUpload: downloadURL };
    return contentRef.update(updateData);

});
```

Now, you are able to perform just 1 query to `fl_content` and the new file's image URL will be included in the request. The tradeoff we make is we have to perform 1 additional Firestore write to save 50% on all future read requests.

Alternatively, without a Cloud Function, we would have to perform 2 separate queries to get the content from `fl_content` and `fl_files`. As Doug mentioned, it is not possible to perform a `JOIN`-like query using Firestore due to the scalable way that it was designed.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to perform a separate query.  There are no SQL-like join operations in Firestore, and references are not automatically followed.

Comment: Doug. I have a bounty here. Edited my question to include my progress in cellForRowAt. Need to "traverse" back out of fl_content into fl_files, to start a new query in getDocument. I don't know what to do after I've gotten document.get("imageUpload")